# Error with reading a file in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

So the following is my code, and my goal is to go through a large .txt file and find the rows with the "stop1" parameter, which should be in the 3rd slot. Then pick up the whole row, and add it in to another file.

```
def reading_files():
 import os
 stop1 = "1040271"

 file1 = open(os.path.expanduser('~/google_transit/stop_times.txt',),'r')

 for row in file1:
    row = row.rstrip()
    parts = row.split(",")
    if parts[3] == stop1:
        file = open(os.path.expanduser('~/timetable.txt'),'a')
        file.write(row)
reading_files()
```

I get the following error:

```
return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 6461: ordinal not in range(128)
```

There was a similar post in here, and answer had to do with coding/decoding, but the file I am handling shouldn't have any weird letters or anything like that.

Comment: it probably has some. have you inspected the contents just to be sure

Comment: Show us the contents of the file.  Also, is that the full stack trace?  Or just a portion of it?

Comment: Please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem. Currently, there is no way for us to verify what you are experiencing.

Comment: Where should I upload the file? Can't put it to pastebin or such since it has thousands of lines of text. And if by full stack trace you mean all of the code, then yes that is it. @mcjoejoe0911

Comment: How bout you give us all of the characters in the 6460-6462 range.

Comment: The byte `0xc3` in UTF-8 is the `Ã ` character.  Are you sure it isn't in your file?  If it is, that's why the `ascii` codec can't interpret it.

Comment: @mcjoejoe0911 not quite, 0xc3 is `Ä` in latin1, `Ä` in utf-8 would be 0xc3 0x83. That means the encoding of the file is probably latin1, so it should be opened with `encoding='latin1'`

Comment: Yeah there indeed seems to be the letter Ä. So how do I do the encoding/decoding? (Very new to python and programming overall so I am quite a beginner with this stuff) @mata

Comment: Adding the "encoding = 'latin1'" to end of the `open()` line removes the errors, but nothing is getting written to the new file. Any ideas? @mcjoejoe0911 @mata

Comment: Can we see what your text file looks like that you're reading in?

Comment: Sure, here is a DL link. [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B70qsForrACtQlNHckhYYkNHOVU/view?usp=sharing) @mcjoejoe0911

Comment: Interestingly enough, the file reads just fine for me even without the `encoding="latin1"` declaration... It also opens just fine if I do specify it... Also, your code writes out to the file just fine for me.  Maybe tell a little bit about how you're running your script?  Is the new file even created when you run your script?  Maybe add some print statements – like where the writing to file happens – and see if they fire.

Comment: I am running it on Eclipse on Mac. Kinda embarrassing, I had forgot to add to call the function..  It did work now with the `encoding="latin1"`. Anyhow, that is all for now, thanks for your time man! @mcjoejoe0911

Comment: Glad it's working!